# Is it possible to make an API call to consume [not publish] various participating restaurants' menus in Google My Business API?

Tags: api, google-api

I found that Google, in December of 2016, enabled Restaurant Menu URL editing in Google My Business API.  I have been unsuccessful in finding any documentation on how [or if it is possible] to retrieve / consume / make API calls to get restaurant menus.

Based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/introducing-structured-menus-in-google?m=0) link it appears that Google has just given businesses the ability to push their menu and or edit their menu.

> "Last December, we enabled Menu URL editing in the Google My Business API allowing businesses to control and manage their menu link on Google Maps and Search. Starting today, businesses that use the Google My Business API can publish their entire menu to Google —"

Any information on how I could make a call to whatever library and retrieve various restaurant menus would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.